# How to ask a question about the selection of one option

Tags: sentence-structure, in-situ-wh-questions

I wrote :

> Which one should Iranians oppose more? Islamic Republic's policies (the regime) or the USA's policies?

On Quora. It says **"it may need editing to be easier to understand. Please double check for spelling, phrasing or other mistakes".**

What is wrong with it? What is the pattern to ask such questions.

Comment: **Which should ...**  or **which ones...** rather than "which one".  Each option is plural.  In English, we would say "the Islamic Republic's..."

Comment: Punctuation:   *Which should ... , A or B?*      That is, a comma separating the  wh-clause from the possible choices, with a question mark at the end.